# get a percentile of filtered criteria?

Tags: excel

I have columns A:D of data, and I want to get a percentile whenever I change up my filters. Is there a way to use the `aggregate` + `percentile` function to define my array in one column (A) and then have it auto update the new 25th or 50th percentile based on newly filtered data? I tried looking at subtotal, but couldn't find a percentile function in the list.

I tried something like `=aggregate(18,4,a2:a9,.25)` to get 25th percentile but it doesn't seem to update with my filtering

Comment: Change the `4` to `5`

Comment: is there a way to make sure that it won't disappear when I start filtering out other criteria in other columns?

Comment: when you filter the row gets hidden, and as such anything on that row gets hidden also.  You will want your output below,above, or on another sheet from the data.

Comment: @ScottCraner can you make an answer so I can give you credit?